# Comparing two lists and printing select columns from each list

Tags: awk

I want to compare two lists and print some columns from one, and some from the other if two match. I suspect I'm close but I suppose it's better to check..

1st file: Data.txt

```
101    0.123
145    0.119
242    0.4
500    0.88
```

2nd File: Map.txt

```
red    1    99     
blue    3    101
rob    3    240
ted    7    500
```

So, if I want to compare the 3rd column of file2 against the 1st of file1 and print the 1st column of file2 and all of file1, I tried `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3];next}$1 in a{print$0}' file2 file1`

but that only prints matches in file1. I tried adding `x=$1` in the awk. i.e. `awk 'NR==FNR {x=$1;a[$3];next}$1 in a{print x $0} file2 file1` but that saves only one value of `$1` and outputs that value every line. I also tried adding $1 into `a[$3]`, which is obviously wrong thus giving zero output.

Ideally I'd like to get this output:

```
blue    145    0.119
ted    500    0.88
```

which is the 1st column of file2 and the 3rd column of file2 matched to 1st column of file1, and the rest of file1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it almost exactly in your second attempt. Just instead of assigning the value of `$1` to a scalar you can stash it in the array for later use.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3]=$1; next} $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' file2.txt file1.txt

$ cat file1.txt
101    0.123
145    0.119
242    0.4
500    0.88

$ cat file2.txt
red   1    99
blue  3    101
rob   3    240
ted   7    500

$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3]=$1; next} $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
blue 101    0.123
ted 500    0.88
```

Comment: Aha.. I was missing the =$1 in a[$3]... I was wondering why adding a[$1] in front of print didn't work...

Comment: @Turtle - you might want to take a second to really THINK about this solution since you apparently thought that without populating it earlier `a[$1]` would somehow contain what you wanted, and that by assigning some value to a different variable after creating the array index (`a[$3];b=$1`) that that would somehow associate the variable `b` with the contents of `a[]`. Arrays in awk are a very common and powerful tool, it's important you understand this very basic application before working on more complex problems. I recommend you get Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.